# Trouble installing pythonbrew on a brand new mac os x lion

Tags: python, macos

I installed pythonbrew, but when I try to install python, I get an error:

```
ERROR: Failed to install Python-3.2.1. See /Volumes/Documents/Users/nathan/.pythonbrew/log/build.log to see why.
```

This is what it says in the log file:

```
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... darwin
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Volumes/Documents/Users/nathan/.pythonbrew/build/Python-3.2.1':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I don't know where the config.log file is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to install XCode from Apple so you get a C-Compiler: you can get it for free from the App-Store [Xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12).

Unfortunately this is the only way I know of to get one - and it is a huge download.

Comment: Pythonbrew also doesn't install cleanly, even with Xcode, for some people. You can find out more here: https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/issues/37

Comment: I'm giving xcode a try now.  Any other version managers for python work better?

Comment: I use homebrew with virtualenv wrappers. But... I do have XCode 4.2 installed so I don't know if you can get by without it.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Lion doesn't include gcc by default -- and, in fact, you'll only have clang (the C frontend for LLVM) if you installed Xcode. Assuming you have that installed, it looks like you can install Pythonbrew by passing the `without-gcc` flag to the configure script.

Comment: I am currently not at a Mac - but I think that XCode will actually come with gcc as well ... I have to check for that later.